Scraping Google Reviews for multiple companies in R and RSelenium yeilding duplicate reviews
I am trying to create a loop that will go Google numerous companies and select the "More Reviews" link and then load all of the reviews.
I have gotten it to go to the step scrolling to the bottom of the reviews, and starting to scrape the review infomration. I seem to be pulling the same review multiple times. I have tried various xpath combinations and am not sure what to change?
Example Company
company <- "5280 Trees"

This will alter become a loop to iterate over all companies in list
  # Navigate to Google
  remDr$navigate("https://www.google.com")

# Find the search box and enter the company name
  search_box <- remDr$findElement(using = "name", value = "q") 
  search_box$sendKeysToElement(list(company, key = "enter"))
# Select the review dialog for scrolling
  select_review_dialog <- remDr$findElement(using = "class", value = "review-dialog-list")

# Scroll within the review dialog
for (i in 1:10) {  # Adjust the loop count as needed
  remDr$executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", list(select_review_dialog))
  Sys.sleep(1)
}



     Sys.sleep(2)  # Pause to let the page load

# Idenentify and click on the more reviews button  
  more_reviews_button <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", value = "//span[contains(text(),'Google reviews')]")
  more_reviews_button$clickElement()
  Sys.sleep(2)  # Pause to let the reviews load
  
# Select the review dialog for scrolling
  select_review_dialog <- remDr$findElement(using = "class", value = "review-dialog-list")

# Scroll within the review dialog
for (i in 1:10) {  # Adjust the loop count as needed
  remDr$executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", list(select_review_dialog))
  Sys.sleep(1)
}

rev_name yields the reviewr name, It is the following 2 (rev_text and rev_score) that are pulling duplicates.
# Scrape for reviewer name 
rev_name <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]) %>% 
  html_elements(".TSUbDb a") %>% #
  html_text() %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  rename(reviewer_name = ".")

Yields:
A tibble:77 × 1
reviewer_name
<chr>
Joshua Riehl                
Sean O'Connor               
Lynn Dexter             
Willy               
James Paris             
Eric Aitken             
Alan Kamp               
Suzanne Cook                
D RDH               
Kirsten Smith

Review:
# Scrape for review text
###THIS YIELDS 4??????
rev_text <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]) %>% 
  html_elements(".Jtu6Td span") %>% #
  html_text() %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  rename(text = ".")

Yields:
A tibble:420 × 1
text
<chr>
I recently had the pleasure of working with 5280 Trees after contacting multiple tree service companies, and I can confidently say they exceeded my expectations in every way. Out of the 7 companies I reached out to, only three responded, and 5280 Trees stood out as the most professional and fairly priced.They removed two large trees from a couple of my rental properties, and even my next-door neighbor commented on how professional the crew was. I initially expected the job to take half a day due to the size of the trees, but the four-member team had everything completed and cleaned up in just two hours.It’s rare these days to find companies that truly deliver value, where you feel like you’re getting more for what you pay. With 5280 Trees, I felt like I paid less and received more. Their equipment was top-notch, and the crew was courteous, efficient, and left the property spotless.I wouldn’t hesitate to use 5280 Trees again, and I highly recommend them to anyone looking for professional, reliable tree services.I recently had the pleasure of working with 5280 Trees after contacting multiple tree service companies, and I can confidently say they exceeded my expectations in every way. Out of the 7 companies I reached out to, only three responded, …More
I recently had the pleasure of working with 5280 Trees after contacting multiple tree service companies, and I can confidently say they exceeded my expectations in every way. Out of the 7 companies I reached out to, only three responded, and 5280 Trees stood out as the most professional and fairly priced.They removed two large trees from a couple of my rental properties, and even my next-door neighbor commented on how professional the crew was. I initially expected the job to take half a day due to the size of the trees, but the four-member team had everything completed and cleaned up in just two hours.It’s rare these days to find companies that truly deliver value, where you feel like you’re getting more for what you pay. With 5280 Trees, I felt like I paid less and received more. Their equipment was top-notch, and the crew was courteous, efficient, and left the property spotless.I wouldn’t hesitate to use 5280 Trees again, and I highly recommend them to anyone looking for professional, reliable tree services.I recently had the pleasure of working with 5280 Trees after contacting multiple tree service companies, and I can confidently say they exceeded my expectations in every way. Out of the 7 companies I reached out to, only three responded, …More
I recently had the pleasure of working with 5280 Trees after contacting multiple tree service companies, and I can confidently say they exceeded my expectations in every way. Out of the 7 companies I reached out to, only three responded, and 5280 Trees stood out as the most professional and fairly priced.They removed two large trees from a couple of my rental properties, and even my next-door neighbor commented on how professional the crew was. I initially expected the job to take half a day due to the size of the trees, but the four-member team had everything completed and cleaned up in just two hours.It’s rare these days to find companies that truly deliver value, where you feel like you’re getting more for what you pay. With 5280 Trees, I felt like I paid less and received more. Their equipment was top-notch, and the crew was courteous, efficient, and left the property spotless.I wouldn’t hesitate to use 5280 Trees again, and I highly recommend them to anyone looking for professional, reliable tree services.
I recently had the pleasure of working with 5280 Trees after contacting multiple tree service companies, and I can confidently say they exceeded my expectations in every way. Out of the 7 companies I reached out to, only three responded, and 5280 Trees stood out as the most professional and fairly priced.They removed two large trees from a couple of my rental properties, and even my next-door neighbor commented on how professional the crew was. I initially expected the job to take half a day due to the size of the trees, but the four-member team had everything completed and cleaned up in just two hours.It’s rare these days to find companies that truly deliver value, where you feel like you’re getting more for what you pay. With 5280 Trees, I felt like I paid less and received more. Their equipment was top-notch, and the crew was courteous, efficient, and left the property spotless.I wouldn’t hesitate to use 5280 Trees again, and I highly recommend them to anyone looking for professional, reliable tree services.
I recently had the pleasure of working with 5280 Trees after contacting multiple tree service companies, and I can confidently say they exceeded my expectations in every way. Out of the 7 companies I reached out to, only three responded, …
we had 5280 out to remove 3 trees and grind down a few other stumps. they were reasonable on their pricing and great on their service. the crew did a great job and we'd hire them again!
we had 5280 out to remove 3 trees and grind down a few other stumps. they were reasonabl

Score:
#scrape for review score
rev_score <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]) %>% 
  html_elements(".z3HNkc") %>% #
  html_attr("aria-label") %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  rename(score = ".")

Yields:
A tibble:157 × 1
score
<chr>
Rated 4.6 out of 5,             
Rated 4.6 out of 5,             
Rated 4.7 out of 5,             
Rated 5.0 out of 5,             
Rated 5.0 out of 5,             
Rated 5.0 out of 5,             
Rated 5.0 out of 5,             
Rated 1.0 out of 5,             
Rated 1.0 out of 5,             
Rated 5.0 out of 5, 

Is anyone able to help me isolate this? or suggest a method that pulls the reviewer name, review, and score all at once? ( I tried using vaipous xpath connectors that I stupidly did not save/write down.)
Bonus points if anyone can add something to capture the date the review was posted or how to add a item to skip companies (once I have the for loop) that do not have the more review option.

I was able to enhance this code a lot and got it to pull the reviews (sometimes it pulls the owners response, need to look into that). I still need to get it to pull the review score easily, but this gets you the reviewer name, how long ago it was posted, and the review.
    all_reviews <- list()

# Loop through the companies
for (company in short_companies) {
  # Navigate to Google
  remDr$navigate("https://www.google.com")

  # Find the search box and enter the company name
  search_box <- remDr$findElement(using = "name", value = "q")
  search_box$sendKeysToElement(list(company, key = "enter"))

  Sys.sleep(2)  # Pause to let the page load

  # Try to identify and click the "more reviews" button, using tryCatch for error handling
  tryCatch({
    more_reviews_button <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", value = "//span[contains(text(),'Google reviews')]")
    more_reviews_button$clickElement()
    Sys.sleep(2)  # Pause to let the reviews load

    # Select the review dialog for scrolling
    select_review_dialog <- remDr$findElement(using = "class", value = "review-dialog-list")

    # Scroll within the review dialog
    for (i in 1:10) {  # Adjust the loop count as needed
      remDr$executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", list(select_review_dialog))
      Sys.sleep(1)
    }

    # Extract reviews and store in a tibble
    reviews <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]) %>%
      html_elements(".gws-localreviews__google-review") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      tibble() %>%
      rename(full = ".") %>%
      # Isolate reviewer name
      mutate(reviewer_name = sapply(str_split(full, "Share"), `[`, 1)) %>%
      # Isolate date
      mutate(
        date_reference = str_extract(full, "(\\d+|a)\\s+(day|month|week|year|days|months|weeks|years)\\s+ago"),
        date_reference = str_replace(date_reference, "^a\\s+(day|month|week|year)", "1 \\1")) %>%
      # Isolate review text
      mutate(review_text = str_extract(full, "(?<=ago)(.*?)(?=\\s*ago)")) %>%
      # Trim trailing date info
      mutate(review_text = str_replace(review_text, "(\\d+|\\ba\\b)[^\\d]*$", "")) %>% 
      # Add company name to the reviews tibble (useful for tracking which company the reviews belong to)
  mutate(company = company)
      #Isolate review score
     
    

    # Append the current company's reviews to the all_reviews list
    all_reviews[[company]] <- reviews

  }, error = function(e) {
    message(paste("No reviews for", company, "or error occurred"))
  })
}

# After the loop, combine all individual company review tibbles into one
all_reviews_combined <- bind_rows(all_reviews)

all_reviews_combined %>% 
  view()

